# How can I solve this problem of state and modules not defined on React in App.js?

Tags: reactjs

[I'm getting this error while I'm trying to add this in the App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xteQ8.png)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import "./App.css";
import Counters from "./components/counters";

function App() {
    state = {
        counters: [
            { id: 1, value: 2 },
            { id: 2, value: 3 },
            { id: 3, value: 0 },
            { id: 4, value: 0 },
        ],
    };
    handleIncrement = (counter) => {
        const counters = [...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index] = { ...counter };
        counters[index].value++;
        this.setState({ counters });
    };
    handleDelete = (counterId) => {
        const counters = this.state.counters.filter((c) => c.id !== counterId);
        this.setState({ counters });
    };
    handleReset = () => {
        const counters = this.state.counters.map((c) => {
            c.value = 0;
            return c;
        });
        this.setState({ counters });
    };
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <NavBar />
            <main className="container">
                <Counters
                    counters={this.state.counters}
                    onReset={this.handleReset}
                    onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
                    onDelete={this.handleDelete}
                ></Counters>
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default App;
```

How can I solve that?

I tried to add a render in the App.js similar as the file of the instructor, but I think its no longer available.

Comment: You have to define the variables and functions. So for example, `state` should be `const state = ...` and for `handleDelete` should `const handleDelete = ...`.

Comment: You're using a functional component. So `this` keyword does not work. `this` keyword is usually used in a Class component.

Comment: Plus, the way you're managing state is wrong. In functional component, we use something called `useState`, have a read at this https://react.dev/learn/managing-state

Comment: Hi do not use this keyword , this keyword is used in class components not in functional component. 
Go through the react documentation for basics

Comment: I was part-way through writing an answer when the list of things wrong with the code just kept piling up in the comments above.  I'm afraid the code you have is wrong in a wide variety of ways, and the only way to really "solve" the problem would be to effectively re-write this entire component.  Which you should do.  But the main two points are: (1) Declare your variables with an explicit scope, don't just rely on implicit globals.  (2) Class-based components and function components are very different.  You can't mix their structure in a single component.  Use one or use the other.

Answer (score 0):

Look's like you are trying to convert an example in React Class Component into a React Function Component. The reason why your code does not work is you are using function as a React Class Component. Assuming that you want to write a Function Component I'll list out the differences and the changes you need to make

### Class Components

In class components the state is an attribute of the instance, i.e. you access the state by using `this.state`. To set the state you use the method `this.setState`.

### Function Component

In function components the state managed by react using the `useState` hook which provides the state and a function to set the state.

### Changes to be made

1. Use the hook `useState`

Import the `useState` hook (which is just a normal function) from react

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
```

2. Declare the state

Instead of writing `state = { ... }` use the hook like

```js
const [couter, setCounter] = useState([ ... ]);
```

3. set the state

Follow what [@Owenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16170683/owenn) says and write the function like this

```js
const handleIncrement = () => { ... }
const handleDelete = () => { ... }
const handleReset = () => { ... }
```

then change the `this.setState` to `setCounter` and `this.state.counter` to `counter`.

### Corrected Code

Here's the correct code

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import "./App.css";
import Counters from "./components/counters";

function App() {
    const [counters, setCounters] = useState([
            { id: 1, value: 2 },
            { id: 2, value: 3 },
            { id: 3, value: 0 },
            { id: 4, value: 0 },
        ]);
    const handleIncrement = (counter) => {
        const counters_ = [...counters];
        const index = counters_.indexOf(counter);
        counters_[index] = { ...counter };
        counters_[index].value++;
        setCounters(counters_);
    };
    const handleDelete = (counterId) => {
        const counters_ = counters.filter((c) => c.id !== counterId);
        setCounter(counters_);
    };
    const handleReset = () => {
        const counters_ = counters.map((c) => {
            c.value = 0;
            return c;
        });
        setCounters(counters_);
    };
    return (
        <>
            <NavBar />
            <main className="container">
                <Counters
                    counters={counters}
                    onReset={handleReset}
                    onIncrement={handleIncrement}
                    onDelete={handleDelete}
                ></Counters>
            </main>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```